# .Net Core API return error msg to Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

Test.cshtml:

```
function insertButton(item) {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/api/test";
        options.type = "POST";
        var obj = datas;
        obj.name = $("#insertName").val();
        obj.url = $("#insertUrl").val();
        console.dir(obj);
        options.data = JSON.stringify(obj);
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.dataType = "html";

        options.success = function (msg) {
            swal({ type: "success", title: msg, showConfirmButton: !1, timer: 2000 })
            getAll();
        },
        options.error = function (msg) {
            swal({ title: "ERROR", text: msg, icon: "error", type: "error", confirmButtonText: "OK" })
        };

        $.ajax(options);
    }
```

TestController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertData([FromBody]Sites sites)
    {
        _context.Add(sites);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return new ObjectResult($"{sites.Name} added");
    }
```

How can I return a message to Ajax `"options.error"`?
And `Name` + `Url` are `"[Required]"` in Model, but empty fields are still saved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not checking if the model is valid or not:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return new BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Add that at the start of your action and you're good to go.

Alternatively, if you're using ASP.NET Core 2.1+, you can simply add the `[ApiController]` attribute to your controller class. Then this check will happen for you automatically.